# Sails.js Waterline ORM or Normal Query. Which one is better?

Tags: node.js, orm, sails.js, waterline

Does Sails.js waterline ORM better than inserting the normal query and executing it? The Sails.js waterline ORM will generate a normal query in its backend and execute it, so can we simply go with the normal query instead of this waterline ORM? can anyone help?

```
Route.findOne({id: routeId}).populate(['operator_id']).then(function(result) {      
  return result
})
```

Here the above waterline ORM will generate the below SQL query only. so why do we have to use the waterline ORM? Is it only useful for adapting the various databases using the same code?

```
SELECT *
    FROM new_route
    INNER JOIN operator
      ON new_route.operator_id = operator.id
    WHERE new_route.id = ?
```

Could anyone help me on this one? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's not better; Waterline ORM provides a **uniform** API for accessing databases, it aims **consistency** across adapters, in some cases you can't use it for some complexe queries and you choose `datastore.manager` to access a raw Mongo collection for example.

Comment: thanks for your response. so can I go with direct query itself instead of this ORM? because finding the method for waterline ORM takes more time to write a complex query.

Comment: I think for simple queries (Create, read, update, delete...) waterline is enough especially for consistency across your app , using natives queries directly for those queries is overkill.

Comment: One advantage of using an adapter like Waterline is that it's possible to switch database implementations (ex during scaling) with very few code changes. Compare that to converting raw SQL queries to any nosql implementation.

Comment: hey @HamzaFatmi i saw that you always aswer sails questions, im migrating to v1 but i got multiple errors, can you help me? i cant make posts